# Map showing the typical rainfall paths

Tags: meteorology, mapping

Hello I am looking for a map that shows the typical (typical for the last 50 years) precipitation paths in the Northern Hemisphere! I already know this [map](http://tropic.ssec.wisc.edu/real-time/mtpw2/product.php?color_type=tpw_nrl_colors&prod=global2&timespan=120hrs&anim=html5), but it only shows a momentary event and does not help me any further.

EDIT:
EG. I mean typical rain paths, such as the water masses for Europe evaporating in the Central Atlantic and then being "pushed" towards Europe between the Azores high and the Icelandic low.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with precipitation paths? Hourly precipitation? Or the total precipitable water which is shown in your link?

Comment: @smichel Is it clear now? If not, please write again :D

Comment: What about seasonal? They change seasonally, so you'd need 3-4 world graphs rather than just one.